# Iterating Pandas Series and replacing float values of given column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So the Date is a timestamp set as index and the Value_col is the the column that I would like to change the first 6 indices to different value than it is originally now.

This is the info the CSV file contains:

```
Date,Value_col
2012-01-01,5444.11111111111
2012-02-01,5555.2222222222
2012-03-01,3333.9629629629
2012-04-01,6666.5714285715
2012-05-01,7777.8965517242
2012-06-01,8888.3703703703
2012-07-01,9999.0
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
  

y_var = pd.read_csv('name.csv')
y_var = y_var.set_index('Date')
y_var = y_var.squeeze()
```

Output datatype:

```
for i,e in enumerate(y.iteritems()):
    print(i,e)
```

Type of Series:

```
0 (Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 5444.11111111111)
1 (Timestamp('2012-02-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 5555.2222222222)
2 (Timestamp('2012-03-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 3333.9629629629)
3 (Timestamp('2012-04-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 6666.5714285715)
4 (Timestamp('2012-05-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 7777.8965517242)
5 (Timestamp('2012-06-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 8888.3703703703)
6 (Timestamp('2012-07-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 9999.0)
```

The idea is to change 5444.11111111111 to 150 000 for instance, 5555.2222222222 to 50 000, thus, each row of Value_col should be changed.

I've tried but series doesnt seem to accept this type of conversion

```
for i,e in enumerate(y_var.iteritems()):
    print(i,e)
    if 5444.11111111111 == e:
        y_var['Value_col'] = y['Value_col'].float.replace(5444.11111111111,1)
```

Comment: if you know the index, you could use `y_var['Value_col'][index] = 150000`

Comment: @Orhan Solak the index is a timestamp in my case 2012-01-01 00:00:00 as the first index row while the value of the column that needs to be replaced is in Value_col however, since it's timestamp and timeseries it doesn't let me even target the col name with y_var['Value_col']. KeyError: 'Value_col'

Comment: I guess I can always recovert the whole Series to DataFrame and replace values. But I thought it should be doable directly in Series as well

Answer (score 0):

Well series are by definition univariate so the concept of column doesn't make a lot of sense in this case.

If you can have the values you want to replace as a mapping dictionary you can do

```py
dict_replace = {
    5444.11111111111: 150000,
    5555.2222222222: 50000
}
y_var.replace(dict_replace, inplace=True)
```

If you don't want to alter the original variable you can then do without the `inplace` flag:

```py
y_new = y_var.replace(dict_replace)
```